# QGIS: tiles from WMS server rendered incorrectly (maybe incorrectly made XML config?)

Tags: qgis, wms

I want to load some tiled map in QGIS. The tiles are okay (I've checked them with `leaflet` map viewer), but when I load them into QGIS (adding WMS config XML file as raster layer), the tiles are rendered weirdly.

[image]

Here's my XML config file (chelyabinsk.xml):

```
<GDAL_WMS>
 <Service name="TMS">
  <ServerUrl>file://path_to_tile_folder_chelyabinsk2_/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl>
  <SRS>3857</SRS>
 </Service>
 <DataWindow> <!--
   <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
   <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
   <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
   <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY> -->
   <UpperLeftX>6621281.138</UpperLeftX>
   <UpperLeftY>7589891.161</UpperLeftY>
   <LowerRightX>6816959.931</LowerRightX>
   <LowerRightY>7301264.942</LowerRightY>
  <TileLevel>14</TileLevel>
  <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
  <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
  <YOrigin>bottom</YOrigin>
 </DataWindow>
 <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
 <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
 <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
 <BandsCount>4</BandsCount>
 <Cache/>
</GDAL_WMS>
```

And here are the tiles: https://www.sendspace.com/file/vvvytc

Can you tell me, how to fix my XML?

Comment: Is it really a WMS, if so why not use the WMS connector in QGIS?

Comment: Well, I've already loaded some tileset (with all world in lowres) via adding its XML from Add Raster Layer, and it worked okay.